# How to provide real-time binding behavior in Aurelia?

Tags: javascript, binding, aurelia

I have a view with button and event handler on button click that calls API and redirects to another view. I'd like to disable this button when event click is triggered.

When I use Aurelia binding

```
<button disabled.bind="loading" type="button" click.delegate="click()">Push</button>
```

and set

```
click() {
   this.loading = true;
   doSomeWork(() => this.loading = false);
}
```

button is still enabled for some time and a user could click this button again.

**I've used a little workaround of it that looks not very good.**

Make ref for button with two-way binding

```
<button ref="button" disabled.two-way="loading" type="button" click.delegate="click()">Push</button>
```

Then I explicitly set disable for button.

```
click() {
   this.button.disabled = true;
   doSomeWork(() => this.loading = false);
}
```

Comment: As I understand doSomeWork(() => this.loading = false && doSomeWork()=> { .... doing ...})); you wana false to be true in second one doSomeWork. False can't be true this way. All fine with Aurelia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably because Aurelia binding uses micro tasks, which are slower than the DOM. Rather than manipulate the DOM in your code, you should check the state of your 'loading' property.

```
click() {
   if (this.loading) { return; }
   this.loading = true;
   doSomeWork(() => this.loading = false);
}
```